# Можно ли сделать такого вида кнопку?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Можно ли инструментами react-a и css сделать подобную кнопку, используя RaisedButton из material-ui?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чистый css же

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #9ad29d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 45px;
  background: transparent; /*или #fff*/
  color: #9ad29d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

<a>кнопка кнопка</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r3v4vkrd/1/

Comment: Рекомендую вам изучить, [как создавать сниппеты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4619). С ними ответы можно делать полностью самодостаточными с рабочим примером, и надобность в ссылках на jsfiddle отпадёт